# How to create a random keyframes name by less fix the space or quote symbol

Tags: css, animation, less, css-animations

I have write a **less** package for my work.

*Some code like this:*

```css
.goTop(@time:1s,@position:-100%){
 @random_suffix:`Math.round(Math.random() * 1.0e8)`;
 @keyframes @random_suffix{
  from{transform:translateY(0);}
  to{transform:translateY(@position);}
 }
 animation-name:@random_suffix;
 animation-duration:@time;
 animation-timing-function:ease-out;
 animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
```

Then I can use it on somewhere I need.

Like this:

```css
.testbox{
  .goTop(1s);
 }
```

**Why I should use a random number?**

Because,if all of the keyframes are the same name,and the last part will overwrite the old part.(the arguments are not the same)

Now,the keyframe name is a random number.

But when the keyframe name is a number,the animation will not run.

So I hope the name like **goTop_12345678**.

I try to contact the string for the variable name.

```css
@temp1:goTop_;
@temp2:`Math.round(Math.random() * 1.0e8)`;
@test:@temp1 + @temp2;
// Error
//{"type":"Syntax","message":"Cannot read property 'numerator' of undefined","filename":"input","index":94,"line":4,"callLine":null,"column":0,"extract":["@temp2:goTop_;","@test:@temp1 + @temp2;",""]}

@temp1:'goTop_';
@temp2:`Math.round(Math.random() * 1.0e8)`;
@test:`@{temp1} + @{temp2}`;
//"goTop_12345678"
//It contains the symbol quote "",and the animation will not run.

@temp1:goTop_;
@temp2:@temp1+`Math.round(Math.random() * 1.0e8)`;
@test:@temp2;
//"goTop_ 12345678"
//It contains the space ,and the animation will not run too.

//For the second and third way
//I have try to use replace way to solve it,but I failed.
```

so,...

How to solve this problem...

**Thanks a lot.**

@cloudhead

Comment: The question is basically "How to concatenate string in Less". [Example](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%5Cnfoo%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct.go-top()%3B%20%20%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.go-top()%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%40random%3A%20%60Math.round(Math.random()%20*%201.0e8)%60%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40name%3A%20~%5C%22go-top-%40%7Brandom%7D%5C%22%3B%20%2F%2F%20%3C-%20here%20we%20go%5Cn%5Ct%40keyframes%20%40name%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ctfrom%20%7Bbar%20%3A1%7D%5Cn%5Ct%5Ctto%20%20%20%7Bbaz%3A%202%7D%5Cn%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Ctanimation-name%3A%20%40name%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%7D).

Comment: For your specific case you can make it [just...](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%5Cnfoo%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct.go-top()%3B%20%20%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.go-top()%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%40name%3A%20~%60'go-top'%20%2B%20Math.round(Math.random()%20*%201.0e8)%60%3B%5Cn%5Ct%40keyframes%20%40name%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ctfrom%20%7Bbar%20%3A1%7D%5Cn%5Ct%5Ctto%20%20%20%7Bbaz%3A%202%7D%5Cn%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Ctanimation-name%3A%20%40name%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%7D). Though in general they usually supply the name as the mixin arg instead of the random hackery (as it's just phew...).

Comment: Thank you very much..you are right.

Comment: But there is a new problem.the random are not the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last solution,some code like this:

```css
.goTop(@time:1s,@position:-100%,@ease:ease-out,@fillmode:forwards){
 .goTopKeyframe(~`'goTop_'+Math.round(Math.random() * 1.0e8)`);
}
.goTopKeyframe(@name){
 @keyframes @name{
  from{transform:translateY(0);}
  to{transform:translateY(@position);}
 }
 animation-name:@name;
 animation-duration:@time;
 animation-timing-function:@ease;
 animation-fill-mode:@fillmode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @seven-phases-max.

the right way to write the var is like this:

```css
@random: `Math.round(Math.random() * 1.0e8)`;
@name: ~"go-top-@{random}"; // <- here we go

//or

@name:~"go-top-`Math.round(Math.random() * 1.0e8)`";
```

But the new problem is that the random number are not the same...

```css
.test {
  background-color: #f39;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 400px;
  -webkit-animation-name: goTop_70024767;
          animation-name: goTop_70024767;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
          animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
          animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes goTop_50030730 {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
            transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}
@keyframes goTop_50030730 {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
            transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}
```

Comment: "But the new problem is that the random number are not the same." - yep, because of lazy-evaluation. It's not a problem to introduce another hack to force the variable evaluation to a single point - but again it's much easier to write the name explicitly... E.g. for your example you already have the unique id which is `.textbox` (it can't have more than one animation anyway)... so just `.goTop(textbox-animation, ...);` there would be much more safe and self-evident.

Comment: [The hack](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%5Cnfoo%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct.go-top()%3B%20%20%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.go-top()%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20passing%20var%20to%20a%20mixin%20forces%20its%20evaluation%3A%5Cn%5Ct.go-top(~%60'go-top-'%20%2B%20Math.round(Math.random()%20*%201.0e8)%60)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.go-top(%40name)%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%40keyframes%20%40name%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ctfrom%20%7Bbar%3A%201%7D%5Cn%5Ct%5Ctto%20%20%20%7Bbaz%3A%202%7D%5Cn%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Ctanimation-name%3A%20%40name%3B%20%20%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%7D).

Comment: By the way."it can't have more than one animation anyway".Yes.But I will use the similar effect for different object,and their arguments are not the same.So I did this for creating the similar animation quickly.TAT

Comment: "I will use the similar effect for different object" - yes, I get that. What I mean that these different object have different selectors anyway.. So you simply would do `.textbox {.goTop(textbox-animation);}`, `.foobox {.goTop(foobox-animation);}` etc. It does not look like a time-saver when you're typing but this will save a lot of time of debugging eventually.

Comment: "Could less add some way to save the random or middle var?" - see my second comment above. As for `random` in general - it's easier to simply provide a built-in function (there's however certain reasons to [have it in a plugin rather than in the core](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2856)).

Comment: Yes.So I delete that.Thanks again